# Roslyn CSharpScript EvaluateAsync Returns False When Statement Should Be True

Tags: c#, roslyn, csharpscript

I am just learning how to use Roslyn and I have a script like this:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
string condition = $@"new List<Guid> {{ new Guid(""{Guid.NewGuid()}""), new Guid(""{id}"") }}.Any(id => id == new Guid(""{id}""));";

var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(condition, 
             Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions.Default
             .WithImports("System", "System.Collections.Generic", "System.Linq")
             .AddReferences(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly)).Result;
```

result is coming back as false.  I even tried:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
string condition = $@"new List<Guid> {{ new Guid(""{Guid.NewGuid()}""), new Guid(""{id}"") }}.Any(id => true);";
```

It also results in false.  I debugged it and grabbed the value in condition and after taking the escaping characters out, it is:

```
var result = new List<Guid> { new Guid("907eb45d-8646-4b1b-baed-54d451f9753a"),
               new Guid("fef76d20-0066-4ee5-901e-2936c2117a8a") }.Any(id => true);
```

Which results in true.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't get a return value. the code should be as follows.

```
string condition = $@"return new List<Guid> {{ new Guid(""{Guid.NewGuid()}""), new Guid(""{id}"") }}.Any(id => id == new Guid(""{id}""));";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but the removing the semi-colon at the end of the statement allowed it to return true.

`string condition = $@"new List<Guid> {{ new Guid(""{Guid.NewGuid()}""), new Guid(""{id}"") }}.Any(id => id == new Guid(""{id}""))";`

instead of:

`string condition = $@"new List<Guid> {{ new Guid(""{Guid.NewGuid()}""), new Guid(""{id}"") }}.Any(id => id == new Guid(""{id}""));";`

Answer (score 0):

`EvaluateAsync` is an async function. It will not return data immediately. You will need to put the `await` keyword before it to wait for the computation.

If you don't, the `result` variable will init with default value `false` when you check it before the `EvaluateAsync` return.

```cs
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(condition, 
             Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions.Default
             .WithImports("System", "System.Collections.Generic", "System.Linq")
             .AddReferences(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly)).Result;
```

You can read more about Asynchronous programming here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: This is not correct.  I was able to access the Result without awaiting and it returned the correct bool value depending on the statement in the eval.  As I stated in my answer, the issue was the semi-colon.